# PHP user as member of a group cannot write to a folder

Tags: centos, permissions, php, nginx

Server is Cento7 running Nginx & PHP. I run Nginx and PHP-FPM as user nginx. nginx is a member of a group called webmasters.

My website is at /var/www/production/site/

Owner of /var/www/production/site/ is other_user:webmasters. Permissions are 0775 These are both applied to all subdirectories.

A PHP script calls file_put_contents() but gets 'permission denied' as it attempts to write to a subdirectory.

If I change the owner of /var/www/production/site/ to nginx:webmasters I do not get permission denied.

SELinux is disabled.

So as a member of a group with RWX it cannot write. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The php-fpm is a separate daemon and it (probably) runs as different user (not nginx).